# How to assign values based on array of to and from indices without a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, loops

Suppose I have a 5 by 5 matrix:

```
matrix = np.zeros(shape=(5,5))
```

And a bunch of indices in to and from format:

```
top = np.array([3,2,3,4,2])
bot = np.array([0,1,2,1,0])
```

How to assign a value to all of those index ranges at once?

```
# here is some pseudo code of what I'm trying to accomplish:
# matrix[bot:top] = 1, or matrix[something] = 1
```

Since top indices and bot indices are arrays I cannot use `bot:top` slicing.

I could solve this with a loop but this would give suboptimal performance when I have millions of values:

```
for i, (t,b) in enumerate(zip(top,bot)):
    matrix[b:t,i] = 1
```

How to do this without looping?

Edit: Here is the expected result after assigning the value.

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

As you can see first column has rows from 0 to 3 changed to 1 and so on.

Comment: I don't think I quite follow the intended logic. For the given `top` and `bot` values, exactly what should the resulting output `matrix` be?

Comment: Edited for clarity with the resulting matrix.

Comment: so you problem is the loop is taking so much time ? if so then maybe push the loop into the c++ side using cython or numba or other jit compilers in order to remove the python loop overhead, and while you are at it, make sure you are striding in a cache friendly way (the inner-most loop should use the second index slot).

Comment: I wonder if there is some function in scipy that maybe doing just that. For example only assign top and bot coords and let it do interpolation.

Comment: There isn't some builtin that does just that.  One way or other  you'll have to iterate, either assigning values in the loop, or collecting indexing arrays as proposed in the answer.  Look at the `np.nonzero(expected)` to see what such a pair of arrays will look like.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like

```py
rows = []
cols = []
for i, (b, t) in enumerate(zip(bot, top)):
    rows.extend(range(b, t))
    cols.extend([i] * (t - b)) 

rows = np.array(rows)
m = np.zeros((5, 5))
m[rows, cols]  = 1.0
```

but I think there has to be some loops in the generation of the indices.

Comment: following @Joooeey linked answer, one can generate cols with `cols = np.repeat(np.arange(len(bot)), top-bot)`